# Unable to find a source package for pidgin (Linux Mint)

Tags: c, plugins, linux-mint, pidgin

I want to start developing Pidgin plugins under [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 13.

I've read [the official tutorial](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/CHowTo/BasicPluginHowto) and at the beginning there's said that I should install the development dependencies for pidgin using the command:  `apt-get build-dep pidgin`

But it ends up with the following error message:

> E: Unable to find a source package for pidgin

Do I have to add a special repository? Or how can I make Linux Mint to find this package?

Here is the dump of sources.list:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```

Comment: which Linux Mint? can you edit your post and dump the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 13 Maya. Post edited...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and add `deb-src`:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import
deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free
```

And try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get build-dep pidgin
```

Comment: You can also add them through the software manager app. go to edit -> software sources, enable source code repositories. Remember to refresh your cache and then you can do apt-get build-dep pidgin

Answer (score 1):

A quick search at `http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php` shows that a Pidgin repo exists for both `felicia` and `helena`, which is Linux Mint 6 & 8 respecitivly. It is possible the repositories that Mint installed by default did not contain links to those particular repositories.

If you are interested in development for Pidgin I would suggest downloading the files directly [from here](http://www.pidgin.im/download/source/). This may help you understand the development process not from the perspective of Mint, but from the perspective of distribution independence.

Comment: thank you, what are those repos? i cannot find anything. Thank you, but when i try it that way i have to install the development dependencies manually, which would be no problem i guess... i will try that...